# Bitcode recompilation of WebRTC targeting tvOS

Tags: ios, xcode, webrtc, tvos, bitcode

I am trying to recompile the bitcode of my tvOS app, including the bundled WebRTC framework, for the purpose of being able to successfully submit the app to the App Store. This same process with the iOS app succeeds.

Upon pushing the tvOS app to the App Store, an email alerts me that:

`ITMS-90562: Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path.`

To diagnose the issue, I switched to an `Ad Hoc` distribution with bitcode rebuilding locally. I did this with both iOS and tvOS so that I could compare the resulting log files.

The earliest difference in the process is this, seen below, where it is apparently putting together a linkage graph.

**iOS**

```
Scanning IPA...
Complete LinkageGraph:
Streamie.app/PlugIns/StreamieNotificationService-iOS.appex/StreamieNotificationService-iOS arm64 ->
    
Streamie.app/Streamie arm64 ->
    Streamie.app/Frameworks/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC arm64
    
Streamie.app/Frameworks/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC arm64 ->
```

**tvOS** (note the `warning`...)

```
Scanning IPA...
warning: Failed to resolve linkage dependency Streamie arm64 -> @rpath/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC: Could not find MachO for /private/var/folders/43/rmt6yww10fg1dbs9tzlfwvlh0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~nvA8Ku/Root/Payload/Streamie.app/Frameworks/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC
Complete LinkageGraph:
Streamie.app/Streamie arm64 ->
```

**$ otool -L WebRTC.framework/WebRTC** (system libs and such removed)

```
WebRTC.framework/WebRTC (architecture arm64):
    @rpath/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

**$ file WebRTC.framework/WebRTC**

```
/[snip]/webrtc/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC: Mach-O universal binary with 1 architecture: [arm64:Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64]
/[snip]/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC (for architecture arm64):   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
```

When the bitcode building process finally fails, the log file concludes with:

```
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:372:in `run'
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2886:in `block in CompileOrStripBitcodeInBundle'
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2825:in `each'
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2825:in `CompileOrStripBitcodeInBundle'
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:3112:in `block in ProcessIPA'
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:3073:in `each'
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:3073:in `ProcessIPA'
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:4035:in `<main>'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExitException: $ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/bitcode-build-tool -v -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin -L --sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS15.2.sdk -o /var/folders/43/rmt6yww10fg1dbs9tzlfwvlh0000gn/T/ipatool20220214-66770-pw6k3b/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/Streamie.app/Streamie --generate-dsym /var/folders/43/rmt6yww10fg1dbs9tzlfwvlh0000gn/T/ipatool20220214-66770-pw6k3b/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/Streamie.app/Streamie.dSYM --strip-swift-symbols /var/folders/43/rmt6yww10fg1dbs9tzlfwvlh0000gn/T/ipatool20220214-66770-pw6k3b/thinned-in/arm64/Payload/Streamie.app/Streamie
Status: pid 66874 exit 1

[snip thousands of lines]

    Search Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/lib/darwin, /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/appletvos, /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS15.2.sdk/usr/lib, /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
    WebRTC not found in dylib search path
```

Some additional notes:

1. I can build-and-run to an Apple TV without issue.
2. I can archive the app and side-load it, and run it on an Apple TV just fine.
3. The resulting iOS and tvOS WebRTC frameworks are each around 620MB, which is roughly the expected size with bitcode enabled.

To build WebRTC targeting tvOS, I'm using a modification of [this script](https://github.com/swarm-cloud/Apple-WebRTC/blob/master/tvosify-sim.sh), seen below, combined with the build script [here](https://github.com/stasel/WebRTC/blob/latest/scripts/build.sh).

```
#!/bin/bash

GN_OUT_PATH=$1

${GN_OUT_PATH}/obj/pc/peerconnection.ninja | awk '{ print $47 }')
IPHONE_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk
TV_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS15.2.sdk

IPHONE_SYSROOT_SED=$(echo "${IPHONE_SYSROOT//\//\\/}")
TV_SYSROOT_SED=$(echo "${TV_SYSROOT//\//\\/}")

ninjas=`find ${GN_OUT_PATH} -name '*.ninja'`
ninjas=$(echo "$ninjas" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ')

for ninja in $ninjas; do
    sed -i -- "s/${IPHONE_SYSROOT_SED}/${TV_SYSROOT_SED}/g" $ninja
    sed -i -- "s/iphoneos-version/appletvos-version/g" $ninja
    sed -i -- "s/arm64-apple-ios/arm64-apple-tvos/g" $ninja
done
```

My best guess at this point is that somehow the bitcode support in the WebRTC framework (for tvOS) is broken, but I don't know how verify that.

Comment: Where you able to figure out this issue?

Comment: Yes. I burned a tech support incident to get the answer. If I recall correctly, the framework's Info.plist described itself as an iOS framework. I made that one small change and everything worked.

Comment: @senojsitruc Small change is  "SupportedPlatform" set as tvos?
Do you have an issue with an unsupported class like AVCaptureDevice on tvos...?

Comment: Yes, @Constantinus. You have to find and remove the classes in WebRTC that require AVCaptureDevice so that they do not build for the tvOS build. It is not a particularly enjoyable process getting WebRTC to work....

Comment: Yes @senojsitruc, I have already done this and WebRTC works perfectly on tvOS.

But I have warning on upload to app connect "The app references non-public in Playload/.....app/Frameworks/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC: isInitialized. startRecording"   

But testFlight works.
Do you know what it this?